# In Relation View, why is it giving me an error, when I am trying to create a foreign key?

Tags: mysql

For my table, I have properly selected the indexes for some of my attributes that I want (4 foreign keys/indexes). Then when I click on Relation View, why is it when I click down to choose the right attribute ('edas'.'vehicle'.'owner') and choose a type for 'ON DELETE' and 'ON UPDATE' 2 out of 4 index/attributes are coming out with an error?

And it does not explain what type of error it is, it's simply just saying error. This is really confusing, can anyone help?

Below shows what one of the error's is coming out as:

Error

```
ALTER TABLE  `vehicle` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `ownerID` ) 
    REFERENCES  `edas`.`vehicle` ( `modelID`) 
    ON DELETE RESTRICT 
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

Comment: 1. Why the PHP tag? 2. If the query is executed by PHP, show the PHP code

Answer (score 0):

One probable reason is that column types are different. If you want to add foreign keys, both columns must have the same type. The onliest difference is that ownerID can be NULL in any case while modelID can be NULL only if ownerID is NULL.